# Can I white list some users to post on my timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

On Facebook I've set "Who can post on your timeline? **Friends**" and "Review posts friends tag you in before they appear on your timeline? **On**".

Can I white list some friends to have them require no review?